# Redirect with HTML vs JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

When would you use meta http-equiv="refresh":

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" />
```

instead of:

```
<body onload="window.location = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'">
```

?

Comment: Probably for users who have javascript disabled

Comment: @DerekPollard Oh, I haven't thought about it. Need to check this one with disabled JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should setup the webserver to return a 301/302 response for redirects. If you want to redirect in an html I'd suggest to show a message like "You will be redirected to: myurl.com" and set a timeout after which you set the location. This way the user knows that there's a redirect :)

Comment: Yeah, I know there are at least 3 ways: 301/302 (Recommended), Javascript, and HTML. Now I'm only curious about HTML vs JS. And I think the answer is in JS availability

Comment: Using the meta tag might look confusing for the user because the page unexpectedly reloads. I would also be worried about how browsers react to those events, e.g. for the browsing history